# cursor intermittent when moving from one monitor to the next

Tags: lenovo-laptop

When I start the computer everything works fine with the mouse.  As I move the cursor from one monitor to the next, as soon as it passes the edge of one monitor, it immediately is picked up on the second monitor.  However, after the computer goes to sleep, when I get back to work, I move the cursor and when it gets to the edge of the monitor, I keep moving the mouse and then after moving the mouse MUCH further, it then gets picked up on the second monitor.  Is that normal or is there something I can do to prevent that?  The refresh rate and screen resolution are the same on both monitors.